# Consume messages from django

Tags: python, django, celery

Is it possible to consume messages from rabbitmq using celery in django?

Messages are being sent from a different non-django app

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery("test")
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.conf.task_routes = { 
  'task.send_emails':{
    'queue': 'sendmail',
    'exchange': 'sendmail',
    'routing_key': 'sendmail'
 }
}
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

Comment: What is the Django's role here? Celery can consume messages and do tasks without help of django

Answer (score 2):

The messages that Celery creates contain the name of the method to be executed and it's parameter list - so no, Celery itself can't consume messages that weren't created in that format for existing, registered Celery tasks.

However, you can use [Kombu](https://github.com/celery/kombu) to achive that - it's part of celery that handles raw message creation and consumption and it's quite easy to use.